# What does DESC do in SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I am confused as to what the word 'DESC' does? What is it's purpose? Could you maybe provide other example, thank you!

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, ROUND(score/(1+(losses/wins))) AS performance FROM images ORDER BY ROUND(score/(1+(losses/wins))) DESC LIMIT 0,10");
```

Edit: Realised this was a dumb question, should of used Google, I now know the answer stop attacking me guys I get it.

Comment: Is Google really that broken? I hear Bing is pretty good these days. Seriously, please put some of your own effort into solving _your own_ problem.

Comment: @Sandeep Please never link to w3schools.com - it's [erroneous in various places](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: @JamWaffles Id have to disagree, I think W3Schools is an excellent place to start.

Comment: @SandeepNair Please don't. Escpacially on the topic of SQL stuff where it will only introduce SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @JamWaffles   I see, I am sorry. Normally I use that for reference

Comment: @Jon There are many better places to go ([HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com/) for example) for tutorials and help. W3Schools is full of errors and does not teach best practices.

Comment: @JamWaffles: Did'nt realize that you posted the same URL above :)

Comment: @verisimilitude The more exposure W3Fools gets the better I'd say!

Comment: Id agree that there are better places to go, however in the case of finding out what a keyword does and learning the very very basics I don't see anything wrong with it.  I do however agree that having the w3schools name may be misleading to some with regards to possible link with w3.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a RTFM question

Comment: @verisimilitude w3fools is as much spam as w3schools. If the information on a page is correct, it doesn't really matter where it is. There are errors on official documentation pages too. That said, when an official page exists, why make do with something else? Go right to the source.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can order your records in ascending or descending order. The default is ASCENDING, which is shortened to `ASC` in SQL syntax. The opposite is of course DESCENDING, which is shortened to `DESC`.

For example,

```
SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id ASC
```

This might give:

```
 id | image
 ---+-----------
 1  | bird.png 
 2  | flower.png
```

However

```
SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC
```

Would give:

```
 id | image
 ---+-----------
 2  | flower.png 
 1  | bird.png
```

Comment: I've edited your answer a little. I hope you don't mind, because now I'd say it's the best answer out of the lot `:)`.

Answer (score 4):

`DESC` means **descending**.

if you have the letters `A`-`Z` in your database, and you sort them by `ASC`, it will go from `A` to `Z`.

`ORDER BY DESC` will sort them from `Z` to `A`.

same goes for `0`-`9`, ascending and descending (for example).

Answer (score 1):

It says "sort in descending order".

It is an optional keyword you can use with `ORDER BY`. (Sorting is done in ascending order by default.)

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY XXX DESC` orders the results in descending order, as opposed to in ascending order ( `ASC`).

Answer (score 1):

`DESC` sorts the resultset in descending order of the column specified, as opposed to ascending `ASC` which is the default

Answer (score 0):

DESC is the explicit word to mention the Order to make it descending. A simple Order by will do it Ascending

Answer (score 0):

It sorts records in descending order.
Know more about Order by [from here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/24/sql-server-interesting-observation-top-100-percent-and-order-by/)

Answer (score 0):

`DESC` means sorting the selected data in descending order.
Example Syntax:

```
SELECT `name` from users where `name` LIKE '%Emmett%' ORDER BY `name`;
```

This would yield/fetch names in Descending alphabetic order